# Display stack.peek in JTextArea

Tags: java

Having trouble using peek and displaying this in a JTextArea. This is the code for my Peek button as it is at the moment:

```
    JButton btnPeek = new JButton("Peek");
    function.add(btnPeek);

    btnPeek.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String peek = stack.peek();
            stackpeek.setText(peek);

        }

    });
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Trying to peek at a stack and display what is at the top of the stack in a JTextArea

Comment: what happens if there isn't anything on the stack? In other words, what happens if it is null? For that matter, what kind of object is on the stack?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? it doesn't compile / method is not called / text not displayed?

Comment: At the moment it says I need to change the type the string to an Integer. However, when I do this, I get an error message on the .setText part and the code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your stack holds Integers, so the `stack.peek()` should return an integer.

However, `stackpeek.setText()` indeed accepts a string.
You can can convert the integer to string like this:

```
int peek = stack.peek();
stackpeek.setText("" + peek);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`String peek = stack.peek();`

with

`String peek = stack.peek().toString();`

**Reason**

From your comments, it seems that your `stack` object is of type `Integer`, not `String`. So the `peek` method on your `stack` object returns `Integer` which you are currently assigning to a variable of type `String`. You should call the `toString` on the `Integer` object returned by `peek` to convert it to a string.

Comment: Says it cannot invoke .toString and also  asks me to change String to Integer again

Comment: What is the type of your `stack` variable?

Comment: public static Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

Comment: I thought so. My answer will surely work. Try again. `String peek = stack.peek().toString();`